# Intuition on the special linear group.

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, intuition

For any (unital and commutative) ring $R$ we can define the *special linear group* as the kernel of the determinant, that is
$$
0 \to \operatorname{SL_n}(R) \to \operatorname{GL_n}(R) \xrightarrow{\det} R^\times \to 0
$$
is an exact sequence.

Of course, when $R = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, this means that we can think of this group as the linear automorphisms of $R^n$ preserving the canonical measure and orientation (by the change of variable formula and the fact that the derivative of a linear transformation is itself).

Is there any way to describe $\operatorname{SL_n}(R)$ in this manner for a general ring?

Perhaps we want to think of an action of $\operatorname{SL_n}(R)$ on the affine $n$-space over $R$ (maybe even using the language of group schemes) and think on some invariant it preserves.
Even better would be to find an algebraic variety (if $R$ is a field) or a scheme which realizes $\operatorname{SL_n}(R)$ as its group of automorphisms.
Are there any results on this?

Comment: Yes. I should make this explicit in my question.
I'm not even sure we can talk about non-commutative determinants... But I guess that's another question.

Comment: There is indeed a notion of non-commutative determinants. Several in fact.

Comment: The affine $n$-space over $R$ is just $\mathbb{A}^n_R=\operatorname{Spec}R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.  We have the sheaf of Kahler differentials $\Omega^1_{R[x_1,\dots,x_n]/R}$ and hence also the invertible sheaf $\Omega^n_{R[x_1,\dots,x_n]/R}$.  Then $SL_n(R)$ is just the subgroup (scheme) of $\operatorname{Aut}_{R\text{-Alg}}R[x_1,\dots,x_n]_{(x_1,\dots,x_n)}=GL_n(R)$ which acts trivially on $\Omega^n_{R[x_1,\dots,x_n]/R}$.  Just like the $R=k$ case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An object left invariant by $SL_n(R)$ is just what you'd think if you already know orientation forms: Define the exterior powers $\bigwedge^\ast M$ of an $R$-module as a quotient of the tensor powers of $M$ as usual. If $M$ is a free $R$-module, say of dimension $n$, then $\bigwedge^n M$ is a free, one-dimensional $R$-module with basis $b_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge b_n$ where $(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ is a any basis of $M$. And you could go ahead and call that an "$R$-orientation of $M$" or something similar. With this definition, all $R$-linear maps $F: M\to M$ satisfy what you'd expect them to satisfy:
$$(\bigwedge^n F)(b_1\wedge\ldots\wedge b_n) = \det(F)\cdot(b_1\wedge \ldots \wedge b_n)$$

In other words: $SL_n(R)$ is precisely the automorphism group of $M$ taken together with any orientation of $M$.

Comment: Very good answer! In hindsight, this is really intuitive.
Perhaps another point of view is that $\operatorname{SL}_n(R)$ corresponds to the automorphisms of the $n$-dimensional affine space preserving the canonical bundle... but I'm still learning these things to be sure this is the case.

Anyway, I'll wait a bit before accepting this answer just to see if someone comes up with something unexpected.